# Всем привет, при запуске данного кода получаю такую ошибку, весь интернет облазил и ничего, помогите кто знает, пожалуйста

Tags: python, авторизация, сессия, telethon

```
from opentele.tl.configs import API
from config import api_hash, api_id
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from python_socks import ProxyType

api = API.TelegramIOS.Generate()

client=TelegramClient('session/79829815504.session', api.api_id, api.api_hash,proxy = (ProxyType.HTTP, '93.190.142.139', 12258, True, '2744931-mobile-country-RU', '2532mo0btx'), system_version=api.system_version, device_model=api.device_model, app_version=api.app_version)
client.start('79829815504')
```

Вот такая ошибка вылазит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mailr\Desktop\0.4Ekat\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.start('79829815504')
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 128, in start
    else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 184, in _start
    await self.send_code_request(phone, force_sms=force_sms)
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 434, in send_code_request
    result = await self(functions.auth.SendCodeRequest(
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in call
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 67, in _call
    future = sender.send(request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 181, in send      
    state = RequestState(request)
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\requeststate.py", line 17, in init    
    self.data = bytes(request)
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\tl\tlobject.py", line 194, in bytes
    return self._bytes()
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\tl\functions\auth.py", line 644, in _bytes        
    self.serialize_bytes(self.api_hash),
  File "C:\Users\mailr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\tl\tlobject.py", line 112, in serialize_bytes     
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: bytes or str expected, not <class 'int'>
```

Что уже делать не знаю, кто сможет, буду рад помощи)

Comment: В заголовке должна быть суть вопроса, а не то что у вас.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, которую вы видите, указывает на то, что где-то в коде ожидается строка или байты, но вместо этого получено целое число (класс 'int'). Вероятно, ошибка происходит из-за того, что вы передаете некорректные значения для параметров, которые ожидают строки или байты. Посмотрим ближе на ваш код:

```
client=TelegramClient('session/79829815504.session', api.api_id, api.api_hash,proxy = (ProxyType.HTTP, '93.190.142.139', 12258, True, '2744931-mobile-country-RU', '2532mo0btx'), system_version=api.system_version, device_model=api.device_model, app_version=api.app_version)
client.start('79829815504')
```

Проблема, скорее всего, находится в одном из параметров, которые вы передаете при создании TelegramClient. В данном случае, вы передаете api.api_id и api.api_hash, которые, судя по всему, ожидаются быть строками, но один из них имеет тип 'int', что вызывает ошибку.

Убедитесь, что значения api.api_id и api.api_hash ваших ключей API (app_id и app_hash) являются строками, а не целыми числами. Вероятно, ваши ключи были некорректно загружены из файла или имеют неверный формат.

Comment: Я хардкодом указал туда данные, все равно та же ошибка(